# Tkinter - Is it possibile to change the color of the ttk.Sizegrip widget?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

in my code I tried to change the color of this ttk widget using the following instruction, but nothing happened:

```
self.style.configure("TSizegrip", bg="red")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `background` instead of `bg`:

```py
self.style.configure("TSizegrip", background="red")
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, it works, but what about the color of the points inside it? I want to change that color too. what is the right option?

Comment: No it cannot be changed according to the [doc](https://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/ttk_sizegrip.htm#M10)

Comment: @TurboC [This](https://gist.github.com/israel-dryer/5ec589c0711ef58dc05626fa06474a65) may help.

Comment: ok guys, at the end I created a new sizegrip using a custom class. it identifies a canvas where I copied the style of the original ttk sizegrip. keep in mind that when we have a different zoom factor than the 100%, you need to fix the pixel width/height with a separate custom function otherwise it will appear smaller than the other widgets. This new widget is completely custom, so you can change the colors and so on (at the end it’s a simple tk canvas).

Comment: I really like Tkinter, but more I use it, and more I see its limitations, .. most of them are really stupids and annoying like in this case, but other ones are really bad, because there are not any kind of workaround for them. the bad management of the memory RAM when we use the tk Text widgets is just an example.